# Inserting new node in XOM to an XML document at a specified Index; using insertChild() method

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xom

I am fairly new to XOM. I want to insert a child(`<stmt> </stmt>`) into the node `<mast_stmt></mast_stmt>` at a specified index but what I get  in the XML document at the correct position is `&lt;stmt &gt; &lt;/stmt&gt;` and this is what I am really after `<stmt> </stmt>`

Here is my code section that handles insertion:

```
 parentNode1.insertChild("<stmt></stmt>", index + 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to create new `Element` instance and pass it as parameter of `insertChild()` :

```java
Element newElement = new Element("stmt");
parentNode1.insertChild(newElement, index + 1);
```